# How to play with White against 3...c5 in modern defense after d4 c4 Nc3 from White

Tags: modern-defense

I play with White 1.d4 2.c4 3.Nc3 against many openings for Black including QGD, KID, Grunfeld, NimzoIndian defense, and Averbach variation in the Modern defense, etc. Recently, I have been facing this line in the Modern defense

```
[FEN ""]
1.d4 g6 2.c4 Bg7 3.Nc3 c5 4.d5 Bxc3 5.bxc3 f5!
```

I tried to look at the database and couldn't find something that I can understand to play against this line. I also tried to look at 4.Nf3 and I didn't like what I saw. Let me know what line do you prefer to play against such a line and the ideas behind it please.

Edit: I found one line that goes like

```
[FEN ""]
1.d4 g6 2.c4 Bg7 3.Nc3 c5 4.d5 Bxc3 5.bxc3 f5 6.e4! fxe4 7.f3! e5 
8.Nh3!
```

It's a crazy line and I believe that Black would be much more prepared than White on average in these positions.

Comment: This is known as the Dzindzi Indian by the way. Named after GM Roman Dzindzichashvili. That might help your searches.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but against the modern, 2. e4 is definitely a better try than c4. It has the added benefit that 3. Nc3 c5 5. dxc5 is a significant improvement for white over the Dzindzi. In fact, the Pterodactyl is nearly refuted with correct play.

Comment: but I'm a d4 player, and many times the position transposes to a KID or Averbach. Thanks for the suggestion anws.

Comment: True. But if you don't play c4 ever in the modern and play with the main line Nc3 stuff instead, then you won't be missing out on any transpositions. White is in control of playing into a KID from the modern. Like I said though, this is not an answer to your original question.

Comment: Would 3.Nf3 be an option?

Comment: First of all, the fact that Black exchanges this important dark-squared bishop for such cheap positional achievement has to be dubious. If I were white, I would not go out of my way to punish this or find a brilliant forced variation to refute something. Simply continue to develop, be ready to sac one of your c pawns, and rest assured that the dark squares weakness (esp. around king) will haunt Black. Or try the following move order: 1.d4 2.Nf3. Transposes to usual Q pawn openings while avoiding/preventing some options for black. For example, 1.d4 g6 2.Nf3 Bg6 3.c4 c5 4.d5; there,s no Bxc3.

Comment: This isn't a modern. The modern defense is a defense to 1. e4 and e4 hasn't been played here.

Comment: @benham- this is actually a very strong line for black. It scores 56.7% for black. You're dismissing it without understanding it. The line you gave will likely transpose to a Benoni but by playing nf3 you've allowed black to avoid the Taimanov which is whites best lines vs the Benoni.

Comment: Yeah, black scores quite well against everything other than 6.e4 fxe4 7.f3.  You could also look at 8. Qc2 instead of 8. Nh3, which also scores well for white with a good eval.

Comment: So many comments and no answer yet.  Seems like the consensus is don't play d4, c4, Nc3 against this.  I mostly play d4, c4, Nc3 as white and modern as Black and was not familiar with this line.  I will look into it.